# How to use a drop down list to reference a different column from a foreign key original table and to save it in foreign keys new table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, foreign-keys

I realise the title might sound confusing so let me try to clarify myself. 
Let's say I have a form which a user can fill out. All the data filled out in this form will be saved to one table. This table has a foreign key which references the id of the other table. The foreign keys original table has two columns, `Id` and `MaterialName`.

I have used a data binder to bind the `MaterialName` from the `Material` table to the drop down list on the form. I would like to be able to save the selected material name from the drop down list into a new table. How do I do this?

I have already tried:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table values('" + TB1.Text + "', '" + TB2.Text + "' , '"+DDLMaterial.SelectedItem.Value+"')", con);
```

And this is how I have referenced my foreign key

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Table_ToTable] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([MaterialID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Material] ([Id] )
```

At the moment the form saves the information but only returns the value "1" in the table and not the corresponding ID. How do I rectify this?

Thank you

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: please place the code your are using to bind the Dropdownlist along with markup of the page.